# How to create multidemensional array and keep adding to it using a session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am trying to create a shopping cart for my website and want to be able to add products to a basket.

So I created an ajax post to a cart.php file in which I start a session if it doesn't exist and then add to it, or only add to the session if it does.

This works when I don't specify the keys like so:

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){
  if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['product'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['price'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['picture'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['quantity'];
 } else {
    //Session is not set, setting session now
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['product'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['price'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['picture'];
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $_POST['quantity'];
 }
}
```

This gives me an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Douche 1
    [1] => 1200
    [2] => cms/images/douche.jpg
    [3] => 
    [4] => Douche 1
    [5] => 1200
    [6] => cms/images/douche.jpg
    [7] => 
    [8] => Douche 1
    [9] => 1200
    [10] => cms/images/douche.jpg
    [11] => 
    [12] => Douche 1
    [13] => 1200
    [14] => cms/images/douche.jpg
    [15] => 
)
```

But later on I want to loop the result, so I need the keys to have useable values not just numbers. So I tried this:

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){
  if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart']['product'] = $_POST['product'];
    $_SESSION['cart']['price'] = $_POST['price'];
    $_SESSION['cart']['picture'] = $_POST['picture'];
    $_SESSION['cart']['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
 } else {
    //Session is not set, setting session now
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart']['product'] = $_POST['product'];
    $_SESSION['cart']['price'] = $_POST['price'];
    $_SESSION['cart']['picture'] = $_POST['picture'];
    $_SESSION['cart']['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];
 }
}
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
Array
(
    [product] => Douche 1
    [price] => 1200
    [picture] => cms/images/douche.jpg
    [quantity] => 
)
```

It replaces itself everytime, so what I am needing is a multidimensional array. My question: how do I create it?

This is the desired result for me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product] => Douche 1
            [price] => 1200
            [picture] => cms/images/douche.jpg
            [quantity] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product] => Douche 1
            [price] => 1200
            [picture] => cms/images/douche.jpg
            [quantity] =>  => 18
        )
)
```

Comment: remove this line $_SESSION['cart'] = array();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your second attemp, try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['product'])){
  $thisProduct = array(
    'product' => _POST['product'],
    'price' => $_POST['price'],
    'picture' => $_POST['picture'],
    'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
  );
  if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $thisProuct;
  } else {
    //Session is not set, setting session now
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $thisProuct;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked, Your post contained a couple of typos though.

Answer (score 3):

simply append the array of data to the session:

```
$product = array(
    'product' => _POST['product'],
    'price' => $_POST['price'];
    'picture' => $_POST['picture'];
    'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'];
);
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $product;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (isset($_POST['product'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][] = [
        'product'  => $_POST['product'],
        'price'    => $_POST['price'],
        'picture'  => $_POST['picture'],
        'quantity' => $_POST['quantity'],
    ];
}
```